# How do I make a function from titration points in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, scipy

I want to automatically calculate a function by giving points on the graph, when I run the following script.

Titration curves are pretty similar to logistic regression, tho, they have different inclinations at the turning points. So it's not 100% the same curve. The best would be to have an output, that gives you the function, similar to this one:
`y = (A) / (1 + B^{x-C}) + D`

Btw. sorry for my english, it's not my native language. ***Please ask questions***, if it is not clear.

```
#from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-plotting-in-python-set-1/ inspired
#YOU HAVE TO HAVE INSTALLED THE FOLLOWING LIBRARIES : matplotlib.pyplot, colorama
# [pip install matplotlib.pyplot]
# [pip install colorama]
# normally alrady installed: math, time

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from colorama import Fore
from colorama import Style
import time

### ANALYTE in ml ###
a = input(" Enter the constant volume of the analyte in ml: ")
print(f"{Fore.GREEN}The volume of the analyte is{Style.RESET_ALL}", a, f"{Fore.GREEN}ml{Style.RESET_ALL}")              
mol_a = input("Enter the molarity of the analyte: ")
print(f"{Fore.GREEN}The molarity of the analyte is{Style.RESET_ALL}", mol_a)
### TITRANT in ml ###
mol_t = input("Enter the molarity of the titrant: ")
t  = float(a)*float(mol_a) / float(mol_t)-0.00001
print(f"{Fore.GREEN}The molarity of the titrant is{Style.RESET_ALL}", mol_t)
# wait 1/2 a sec
print("calculating...")
time.sleep(.5)
print(f"{Fore.GREEN}The volume of the titrant under the equivalence point is{Style.RESET_ALL}",t, f"{Fore.GREEN}ml{Style.RESET_ALL}")
#Volumeof titrant in ml:
t0= 0.00001
t1= math.trunc(float(t)*10000)/10000
t2= float(t)*0.9999
t3= float(t)*0.999
t4= float(t)*0.99
t5= float(t)*0.97
t6= float(t)*0.9
t7= float(t)*0.7
t8= float(t)*0.5
t9= float(t)*0.3
t10= float(t)*0.1
t11= (float(t1))*1.0001
t12= (float(t1))*1.001
t13= (float(t1))*1.01
t14= (float(t1))*1.03
t15= (float(t1))*1.1
t16= (float(t1))*1.3
t17= (float(t1))*1.5
t18= (float(t1))*1.7
t19= (float(t1))*1.9
t20= (float(t1))*2
# mol of Analyte and Titrant:
anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt = float(a)* 10**(-3)*float(mol_a)
#M                            =             z.B. 0.005      mol
anzahl_mol_von_starker_titrant = float(t)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t)
#pH at this ratio:
berechne_pH_t0       =     (-1)*math.log10(        (float(anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt) -    float(float(t0)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t)))       /       (float(t0)*10**(-3)  + float(a)*10**(-3)   )       )
berechne_pH_t1       =     ( 7)
berechne_pH_unter_t2 =     (-1)*math.log10(        (float(anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt) -    float(float(t2)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t)))       /       (float(t2)*10**(-3)  + float(a)*10**(-3)   )       )
berechne_pH_unter_t3 =     (-1)*math.log10(        (float(anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt) -    float(float(t3)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t)))       /       (float(t3)*10**(-3)  + float(a)*10**(-3)   )       )
berechne_pH_unter_t4 =     (-1)*math.log10(        (float(anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt) -    float(float(t4)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t)))       /       (float(t4)*10**(-3)  + float(a)*10**(-3)   )       )
berechne_pH_unter_t5 =     (-1)*math.log10(        (float(anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt) -    float(float(t5)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t)))       /       (float(t5)*10**(-3)  + float(a)*10**(-3)   )       )
berechne_pH_unter_t6 =     (-1)*math.log10(        (float(anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt) -    float(float(t6)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t)))       /       (float(t6)*10**(-3)  + float(a)*10**(-3)   )       )
berechne_pH_unter_t7 =     (-1)*math.log10(        (float(anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt) -    float(float(t7)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t)))       /       (float(t7)*10**(-3)  + float(a)*10**(-3)   )       )
berechne_pH_unter_t8 =     (-1)*math.log10(        (float(anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt) -    float(float(t8)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t)))       /       (float(t8)*10**(-3)  + float(a)*10**(-3)   )       )
berechne_pH_unter_t9 =     (-1)*math.log10(        (float(anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt) -    float(float(t9)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t)))       /       (float(t9)*10**(-3)  + float(a)*10**(-3)   )       )
berechne_pH_unter_t10 =    (-1)*math.log10(        (float(anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt) -    float(float(t10)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t)))      /       (float(t10)*10**(-3) + float(a)*10**(-3)   )       )
berechne_pH_ueber_t11 = 14-(-1)*math.log10(        (float(float(t11)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t) - (float(anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt))))       /       (float(t11)*10**(-3) + float(a)*10**(-3)   )       )
berechne_pH_ueber_t12 = 14-(-1)*math.log10(        (float(float(t12)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t) - (float(anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt))))       /       (float(t12)*10**(-3) + float(a)*10**(-3)   )       )
berechne_pH_ueber_t13 = 14-(-1)*math.log10(        (float(float(t13)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t) - (float(anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt))))       /       (float(t13)*10**(-3) + float(a)*10**(-3)   )       )
berechne_pH_ueber_t14 = 14-(-1)*math.log10(        (float(float(t14)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t) - (float(anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt))))       /       (float(t14)*10**(-3) + float(a)*10**(-3)   )       )
berechne_pH_ueber_t15 = 14-(-1)*math.log10(        (float(float(t15)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t) - (float(anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt))))       /       (float(t15)*10**(-3) + float(a)*10**(-3)   )       )
berechne_pH_ueber_t16 = 14-(-1)*math.log10(        (float(float(t16)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t) - (float(anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt))))       /       (float(t16)*10**(-3) + float(a)*10**(-3)   )       )
berechne_pH_ueber_t17 = 14-(-1)*math.log10(        (float(float(t17)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t) - (float(anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt))))       /       (float(t17)*10**(-3) + float(a)*10**(-3)   )       )
berechne_pH_ueber_t18 = 14-(-1)*math.log10(        (float(float(t18)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t) - (float(anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt))))       /       (float(t18)*10**(-3) + float(a)*10**(-3)   )       )
berechne_pH_ueber_t19 = 14-(-1)*math.log10(        (float(float(t19)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t) - (float(anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt))))       /       (float(t19)*10**(-3) + float(a)*10**(-3)   )       )
berechne_pH_ueber_t20 = 14-(-1)*math.log10(        (float(float(t20)*10**(-3)*float(mol_t) - (float(anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt))))       /       (float(t20)*10**(-3) + float(a)*10**(-3)   )       )
# X-axis: Volume of Titrant in ml:
x = [float(t0),float(t1),float(t2),float(t3),float(t4),float(t5),float(t6),float(t7),float(t8),float(t9),float(t10),float(t11),float(t12),float(t13),float(t14),float(t15),float(t16),float(t17),float(t18),float(t19),float(t20)]
# Y-axis: pH-value at this ratio:
y = [berechne_pH_t0,berechne_pH_t1,berechne_pH_unter_t2,berechne_pH_unter_t3,berechne_pH_unter_t4,berechne_pH_unter_t5,berechne_pH_unter_t6,berechne_pH_unter_t7,berechne_pH_unter_t8,berechne_pH_unter_t9,berechne_pH_unter_t10,berechne_pH_ueber_t11,berechne_pH_ueber_t12,berechne_pH_ueber_t13,berechne_pH_ueber_t14,berechne_pH_ueber_t15,berechne_pH_ueber_t16,berechne_pH_ueber_t17,berechne_pH_ueber_t18,berechne_pH_ueber_t19,berechne_pH_ueber_t20 ]
# Hiermit werden die Punkte in das Koordinatensystem geplottet:
plt.scatter(x, y, label= "values", color= "green", 
            marker= "o", s=30) 
# X-axis; title:
plt.xlabel('Volume of titrant in ml')
# Y-axis; title:
plt.ylabel('pH-value at this ratio')
# Title of graph:
plt.title('Titration curve, strong acid, strong base')
# show legend
plt.legend() 
# show plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: I tidied the question. Please check that I have not changed the meaning. I think it was clear. I just did some formatting, and fixed some annoying bits (being told “as you can see“ before I got to the bit you were telling be about, I was just about to see it. Being told that you had told me, I know what you told me, but it left we wondering where, had you told us in another post. I assume you meant the title, it which case we don't need to be told how to read it. Then you were telling "you" when it was not about me. These are typical mistakes made by native speakers. Your English is good.

Comment: Thank's a lot for the correction!

Comment: Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fit the parameters of a parametric function to data, you can use [**`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html):

```
def my_function(x, A, B, C, D, E):
    return A/(1 + B**(x - C)) + D + E*x

parameters, covariance = curve_fit(f = my_function, xdata = x, ydata = y)
```

If necessary, you can improve the results by passing some bounds for the parameters:

```
parameters, covariance = curve_fit(f = my_function, xdata = x, ydata = y, bounds = ([0, 0, 0.9*t, -10, -10], [14, 1, 1.1*t, 10, 10]))
```

### Complete Code

```
# IMPORT
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


# INPUT VALUES
a = 100
mol_a = 10
mol_t = 5


# DATA GENERATION
N = 40
t  = a*mol_a/mol_t

x1 = np.linspace(0, t - 1e-6, N//2)
x2 = np.linspace(t + 1e-6, 2*t, N//2)
anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt = a*10**(-3)*mol_a
anzahl_mol_von_starker_titrant = t*10**(-3)*mol_t

y1 = (-1)*np.log10((anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt - x1*10**(-3)*mol_t)/(x1*10**(-3) + a*10**(-3)))
y2 = 14 - (-1)*np.log10((x2*10**(-3)*mol_t - anzahl_mol_von_starker_analyt)/(x2*10**(-3) + a*10**(-3)))

x = np.concatenate((x1, x2))
y = np.concatenate((y1, y2))


# PARAMETERS FITTING
def my_function(x, A, B, C, D, E):
    return A/(1 + B**(x - C)) + D + E*x

parameters, covariance = curve_fit(f = my_function, xdata = x, ydata = y, bounds = ([0, 0, 0.9*t, -10, -10], [14, 1, 1.1*t, 10, 10]))

for parameter, name in zip(parameters, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']):
    print(f'{name} = {parameter:14.10f}')

x_fitted = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 1000)
y_fitted = my_function(x_fitted, *parameters)


# PLOT
plt.style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y, label = 'data', marker = 'o', linestyle = '')
ax.plot(x_fitted, y_fitted, label = 'fitted curve')

ax.set_xlabel('Volume of titrant in ml')
ax.set_ylabel('pH-value at this ratio')
ax.set_title('Titration curve, strong acid, strong base')
ax.legend(frameon = True)

plt.show()
```

### Result

```
A =  13.2787117583
B =   0.7311691018
C = 199.8189983959
D =  -0.8940392051
E =   0.0054250609
```

### PLOT

[image]

Comment: On the face of it, the fitted curve isn't a good fit; is the parameter C much too large? I guess I would expect a softer fitted curve; the one shown is approximately a step function.

Comment: The `C` parameter is the best fitted one among them, in fact it should be `200`, since this is the value at wich data pass from "low" values to "high" values, for the choosen set of input. The model curve itself is not a good choice to fit this kind of data, since it reaches the asymptotes too fast, while data seem to have a linear asymptote. In any case, I have updated my answer using a different fitting curve model, check the result and let me know if it is good for you.

Comment: Oh, you're right about C, it should be about 200 as you were saying. The revised plot looks like a better fit.

Comment: I was notified about your most recent comment; did you mean to address it to OP?

Comment: Dear Zephyr, thanks a lot for helping me, it works fine now. I already thougt of something like that, but simply couldn't write it in code. I'm utterly new to the numpy and scipy libraries. Also, the thing with improving results with the bound for the parameter is an excellent idea. Thank you!